# Converting data.frame with no lat-long info to raster using R?

Tags: raster, r

I need to read in a .txt file into R and later do some spatial analyses on it.
I’m working in R. 3.0.2 on a Windows server.
I load the following libraries (probably more than I need):

> library(raster)
>   library(rgdal)
>   library(rgeos)
>   library(sp)
>   I then read in the text file:
>   v2<-read.delim("E:\GIT\GEO_04_Research\03_Fire\03_FireIASI\Data\fire\GigGFEDRedownload\GFED3.1_199902_BA.txt", header=FALSE, sep = "",  dec = ".", strip.white=TRUE)
>   This works fine and
>   str(v2)   #tells me 'data.frame':  360 obs. of  720 variables.

However, there is no xy information.  The documentation on this data layer states this data runs from a top-left of 179.75W, 89.75N to the lower right corner at 179.75E, 89.75S, with each reading in this regular ‘grid’ occurring at 0.5 degrees.

So I created a raster to match these specifications:

> gfed<-raster(ncol=720,nrow=360,xmn=-89.75,xmx=89.75,ymn=-179.75,ymx=179.75)
>   gfed… # tells me:
>       class       : RasterLayer
>       dimensions  : 360, 720, 259200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
>       resolution  : 0.2493056, 0  (x, y)
>       extent      : -89.75, 89.75, -179.75, 179.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>       coord. ref. : NA

But now how do I get the xy information from the ‘gfed’ raster onto the values in the data ‘v2’?

I tried ‘stack’ hoping it would take the ‘square’ data.frame onto to the gfed raster, but I get 0 layers.  I’m new to coding and I suspect that this requires some loop that reads row 1 from 1-720 and then goes to the next row until it reads all 360 rows.

I think part of the problem is that the data.frame ‘v2’ doesn’t have any spatial information associated with it, so SpatialPixels and SpatialDataFrame options don’t work – or at least, I can’t get them to work.

I just can’t get passed this point.

---

I'm almost there with your solution of using 'scan' into a newly created raster.  It is a bit embarrassing to admit – I understood that my co-author on this was sending ‘world-wide’ files at half-degree scale, and previous data have been just that, and so I accepted that even though I looked at the data and saw co-ordinates that didn’t start at -180, +90.  The study area is actually southern Africa (approximately xmn=13, xmx=36, ymn=-36, ymx=-18) and it is at a quarter-degree (0.25) scale!
I thought I’d be very clever and apply your solution (make grid and then scan the data in to the new grid) with these southern Africa parameters.  I couldn’t get it to work and after spending time staring at the data, I realised two things:

1. The points don’t start neatly at round numbers.  I applied shifts separately to the x and y.

   2. Then I realised that the data that has been sent to me is an irregular grid.  It is not consistently 0.25-degrees.  It is in general has a 0.3-degree sized grid cell followed by a 0.2- degree sized grid cell followed by another 0.3- degree sized grid cell.

Any idea how I read/scan data from an irregular ‘grid’ into a nice neat 0.25 grid that I have made.  I have now made

> southernA<-raster(nrow=72, ncol=92, xmn=13, xmx=36, ymn=-36, ymx=-18)

I guess I would like R to ‘resample’ the ‘nearest-neighbour’ grid from the irregular grid into my newly created, regular grid called southernA.

Someone asked what the data is all about:  we are looking to see how much biomass burning contributes to CO in the atmosphere.  I used to do a lot of fire ecology work for a conservation agency that I worked for.  I still dabble in the field.   I’d be happy to post a copy of the irregular grid data if that would help find the solution.

Comment: If you don't have spatial information in the df or supporting information about which row/cell represents which location, there is no way to put this into a raster. Please post sth like `head(v2)` to give us a clue what this data shows.

Comment: `head(v2)` will give us 6 rows of 720 numbers...

Comment: Sure you got x and y right? That's surely degrees, and x goes from -180 to 180... (longitude)

Answer (score 4):

So I've created a file that reads into a data frame in the same way as yours:

```
> str(v2)
'data.frame':   360 obs. of  720 variables:
```

BUT data.frame isn't really the right thing here. Its really meant for record-oriented data, where each row is a record and each column is a potentially different variable for that record (eg each row is a person, the columns are name, age, height, etc).

So you really only need to `scan` the data in as one long vector and feed it to a raster.

Step 1, define an empty raster of the right size and shape (note I'm assuming the raster covers the whole world, so the limits are not the cell centres):

```
> m2=raster(nrow=360,ncol=720,xmn=-180,xmx=180,ymn=-90,ymx=90)
```

Step 2, read numeric values into the raster data slot:

```
> m2[]=scan("d.txt",what=1)
Read 259200 items
```

And give it a projection if needed:

```
> projection(m2)="+init=epsg:4326"
> plot(m2)
```

If you want to check that the resolution and the cell centres are as expected, use these functions:

```
> res(m2)
[1] 0.5 0.5
> xFromCol(m2,1:10)
 [1] -179.75 -179.25 -178.75 -178.25 -177.75 -177.25 -176.75 -176.25 -175.75
[10] -175.25
> yFromRow(m2,1:10)
 [1] 89.75 89.25 88.75 88.25 87.75 87.25 86.75 86.25 85.75 85.25
```

which shows the resolution is half a degree and the cell centres (or at least the first 10) are at those specified coordinates.

Comment: Dear Spacedman!  Thanks so much for your solution - I think it is the correct approach, but I had some glitches due to my own fault - not looking at the data thoroughly enough.. due to space, I'm going to try report back and ask for new help (pretty please) in a new 'Answer Your Question' below...Tx

Comment: If its just an adjustment to your question you should edit your question above rather than add an answer below - unless you are really answering your question!

Answer (score 1):

You started right with the:

```
gfed<-raster(ncol=720,nrow=360,xmn=-89.75,xmx=89.75,ymn=-179.75,ymx=179.75)
```

Then you can define the projection and set the resolution right:

```
projection(gfed) <- "+proj=utm +zone=48 +datum=WGS84" # for example
res(gfed) <- 100
```

Finally, you can use:

```
gfed[]<-v2
```

to put your data in the raster.

Comment: A 'gotcha' here is that the `xmn,xmx` etc parameters to `raster` specify the outer edges of the cells and not the cell centre points. So when I see a raster that has a limit of '179.75W' I suspect that's probably a cell centre, and the cell extent is actually 180W to 179.5W, so `ymn` should be -180 so the grid covers the whole world. Similarly for the other extents.

Comment: I'm also not sure where you got that projection from. This looks like lat-long degrees, most likely WGS84, so `"+init=epsg:4326"`.